# track a file with git repo as well as separate git bare repo

Tags: git, git-add, git-bare, git-worktree

I use to manage my dotfiles with a git bare repository.
However some of my dotfiles are already in git repositories existing for a long time.
I dont want to lose all the change history so I would prefer keeping the repo.

When I try to add those files into my git bare repository git seems to ignore them.
Is there any way to have the same file in two different repos (one a local git repo and one a git bare repo)?

Best regards

I did
`git --git-dir=/home/user/.dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME add localrepo/file`
and expected the file `localrepo/file` to be staged.

`localrepo` is a git repository itself and nothing happened.
If I do the same for files which are not in git repositories everything happens as expected

Comment: step one: check your `.gitignore` file. But I'm a bit confused by your claim that you "dont want to lose all the change history". that's literally the point of git: you don't lose change history by overwriting a file, you just _add another change_ to the change history.